# Twitter API status update not working when updating to v1.1

Tags: coldfusion, twitter, http-status-code-401

I have a twitter application which sends tweets automatically for uses of our blog application whenever they post a new blog item.

This application is now returning an error

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 22:05:27 UTC Server: tfe
>
> {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}

My coldfusion code is as follows for posting the tweet:

```
<cfset var tweetURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json">
<cfhttp url="#tweetURL#" method="post" result="result">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#oauth.header#" encoded="no">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="status" value="#tweet#" encoded="no">
</cfhttp>
```

I have dumped out all the oauth header values, they are all as they should be, they are not returning any errors at all. its only the status update that is returning the unauthorized error.

What other things do I need to check? I thought my app may have been blocked or something but its all up and working. I've tested the user accounts they have authorized the app.

Comment: I know this is one of those vague irritating questions. but I don't know how to go about troubleshooting it. I mean it worked, then it didn't. I went through all the oauth testing when I first developed it. The functions work. It just seems to be at the time of posting that things go wrong

Comment: I just used http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html to double check that my header and signature were being created correctly.   They are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out. I was to busy validating the input of the header and auth tokens etc that I overlooked the status. It wasn't urlencoded. although this apparently worked in the old version. it didn't pass for the new.